# How to apply promises on a for loop using Q library?

Tags: node.js, express, promise, q

In this code for loop runs only for the first time. Please tell me how I can correct it. I need function get_profile_image() to run before it starts executing next values of loop.In this code for loop runs only for the first time.

```js
function response(){
       var deferred = q.defer();

     for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++){


       var from_name = results[i].from_name;
       var request_from =  results[i].request_from;

       var empty = new Array();
       friend_requests.push(empty);
       friend_requests[i].push(from_name);
       friend_requests[i].push(request_from);
       var new_array = friend_requests[i];
       function get_profile_image(){
         var profile_image_defer = q.defer();
         var dir = "./public/img/users_directory/"+request_from;
         fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
             files.forEach(function(f) {
                 var file = f.substr(0, f.lastIndexOf('.'));

                 if(file === "profile_image"){
                   profile_image = "../img/users_directory/"+email+ "/" +f;
                   new_array.push(profile_image);
                 }
             });
             profile_image_defer.resolve(profile_image);
           });

           return profile_image_defer.promise;

       }
       
       get_profile_image().then(function(){
         deferred.resolve(friend_requests); //This runs only for first time i.e. i=0

       });

      return deferred.promise;

     }




   }
   response().then(function(){
     console.log(friend_requests);
     res.send(friend_requests);
   })
```

Comment: you are returning inside the for loop - which is why it only runs once

Comment: Would be better if you try to describe your problem instead of showing your code because is unreadable and wrong in some many ways...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a loop, try using `results.map()` with a function that returns a promise for every result.

Right now you are trying to return many times from the same functions which is impossible - well, it's kind of possible with generators but it's not the same.

IF you have a function that takes one element of `result` and returns a promise than you'll be able to use it with `results.map()` and then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of the promises.

There are too many problems with your code to just point to one fix. You probably need to write it from scratch. What you should keep in mind is that you cannot use `return` multiple times in the same function because the first return will, well, return from the function and the function will not run anything else. The return statement terminates even generators.